# Can't get Find() method in EntityFramework 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
   { 
       using (var db = new BlogDataEntities()) 
       { 
           return View(db.Blogs.Find(id)); 
       } 
    }
```

I have been going though this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg685489, however in my IDE i am not able to get the method `Find()` on `db.Blogs`  and i'm using EntityFramework 4.1.0.0, MVC 3 and .NET 4.0

I have even had a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/28/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-3-finding-entities.aspx but cannot get the Find() method.

Any idea why i am not able to get the Find method on db.Blogs?

Comment: Did you add "ADO.NET DbContext Generator"?

Comment: Thanks @BappiDatta, it was my mistake, i had added "ADO.NET EntityObject Generator" instead of "ADO.NET DbContext Generator". Please post you comment as answer and i wil accept it.

Comment: Also i think i need to get a solid understanding of the differences between ADO.NET DbContext Generator, ADO.NET EntityObject Generator and ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator, do you of an article i can read to completely understand those 3.

Comment: Thanks. I have post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add "ADO.NET DbContext Generator".